# Displaying A Notification When I Want?

Tags: android, notifications

How can I send a notification when I want? Example, I want display a notification about new update, announcement... A custom notification. Is it possible? Is there a library?

Comment: It seems like a push service.Try use Google GCM.

Comment: @tinysunlight trying now

Comment: @Ataberk Please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto Can you edit for better?

Comment: @Ataberk Please read the page I've linked to. Your question is highly subjects to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Parse Android notification API:

http://www.parse.com

Here is the instruction of how to import and activate the API on your project:

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

Then all what you need to do is to go to parse site and send the push notification:

https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

The notification sending looks like that:
[image: How you send the notification]

There is one Catch here:

[image: Catch]

Comment: _explanation_: I can't see `parse.com` tag.

Comment: Is it completely free or limit?

Comment: So what? he didn't specify a way that he want to send his notification...

Comment: @DeBanana Such questions MUST be closed not answered.

Comment: Ok so don't down vote me i just want to help people... Down vote him if you don't like his way of asking a question...

Comment: @DeBanana Okay, upvoted!

Comment: @Ataberk There is a limit but its hard to pass it...